# How to make SwiftUI List/OutlineGroup lazy for use with large trees like a file system?

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-outlinegroup

Here's a simple demo of the hierarchical `List` in SwiftUI. I'm testing it on macOS Big Sur, but unlike similar tree components in other UI toolkits, it asks for all its children immediately. So I can't use it for something like a file system browser.

Is there a way to make it lazy, so that it only asks for `children` when the UI element is expanded?

```swift
class Thing: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let depth: Int
    let name: String
    init(_ name: String, depth: Int = 0) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.depth = depth
    }
    /// Lazy computed property
    var children: [Thing]? {
        if depth >= 5 { return nil }
        if _children == nil {
            print("Computing children property, name=\(name), depth=\(depth)")
            _children = (1...5).map { n in
                Thing("\(name).\(n)", depth:depth+1)
            }
        }
        return _children
    }
    private var _children: [Thing]? = nil
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var things: [Thing] = [Thing("1"), Thing("2"), Thing("3")]
    var body: some View {
        List(things, children: \.children) { thing in
            Text(thing.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the initial UI only displays the top nodes:

[image]

You can see in the console that it asks for everything - all the way down the tree. This is a performance problem for large trees.

```
...
Computing children property, name=3.4.4.1.4, depth=4
Computing children property, name=3.4.4.1.5, depth=4
Computing children property, name=3.4.4.2, depth=3
Computing children property, name=3.4.4.2.1, depth=4
Computing children property, name=3.4.4.2.2, depth=4
...
```

Comment: Works fine with iOS 14, so seems this macOS issue.

Comment: Others have observed this on macOS, as seen at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662937 (FB8782243). It does render the OutlineGroup useless for any sort of deep or lazy hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be a bug in SwiftUI and I hope Apple will fix this. In the meantime, you can use the following workaround:

```swift
struct Node {
    var id: String
    var value: String
    var children: [Node]?
}

struct LazyDisclosureGroup: View {
    let node: Node
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        if node.children != nil {
            DisclosureGroup(
                isExpanded: $isExpanded,
                content: {
                    if isExpanded {
                        ForEach(node.children!, id: \.self.id) { childNode in
                            LazyDisclosureGroup(node: childNode)
                        }
                    }
                },
                label: { Text(node.value) })
        } else {
            Text(node.value)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let node = Node(
        id: "a",
        value: "a",
        children: [Node(id: "b", value: "b", children: nil),
                   Node(id: "c", value: "c", children: nil)])
    var body: some View {
        List {
            LazyDisclosureGroup(node: node)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if that's a best practice but the workaround uses the observation that `DisclosureGroup` "notices" when it is inside a `List`. The combination of the two produces the same visual structure and behaviour.

Comment: Hello Skimble! I was hopeful for your approach here and tried it out. I found that it seems to frequently not work very well. If I open the tree up, then close and open a high level node, many of the child nodes won't open again. Thinking the state might be getting destroyed when nodes are closed, I tried moving the `isExpanded` state to the Node as `@Published` and conformed `Node: ObservedObject` but this didn't resolve it.